# ant task to deploy/undeploy war on jboss

Tags: ant

How do i deploy/undeploy a war file on running Jboss server using ANT build ?

Answer (score 5):

JBoss AS7 has a deployment scanner enabled by default, so you can just copy the war file to ${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments and it will automatically be deployed, ie:

```
<copy file="${war.path}" todir="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments"/>
```

Once the war is deployed, a file called ${war.filename}.war.deployed will appear in the deployments directory. To undeploy a war, delete the related .deployed file, ie:

```
<delete file="${jboss.deployments.dir}/${war.filename}.war.deployed"/>
```

Once the war has been undeployed, there will be a file called ${jboss.deployments.dir}/${war.filename}.war.undeployed in the deployments directory.

To prompt a redeployment, you can either delete the .undeployed file, or create a file with the same name as the war and a .dodeploy extension, ie:

```
<touch file="${jboss.deployments.dir}/${war.filename}.war.dodeploy"/>
```

[This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013783/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-jboss-as-7) has an example of an Ant task for an undeploy followed by a deploy.

Obviously, for the above to work you need to declare the various properties used somewhere, ie:

```
<property name="war.filename" value="mywar" />
<property name="war.path" value="dir/mywar.war" />
<property name="jboss.deployments.dir" value="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JBoss Web Client Deployer](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/deployer-howto.html#Deploying%20using%20the%20Client%20Deployer%20Package)

> The deployer is not packaged with the
>   JBoss Web core distribution, and must
>   therefore be downloaded separately
>   from the Downloads area. The download
>   is usually labelled
>   jbossweb-2.1.x-deployer

I have not used this myself

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the version of JBoss used by you.However you can you cargo library for deploying/undeploying your application in JBoss.

For more info on cargo refer to : [Cargo Ant support](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Ant+support)

Answer (score 0):

You can just

```
<copy file="${war.path}" todir="${jboss.home}/server/default/deploy"/>
```