# Why is JBoss-7.2.0 app not working after porting it from Tomcat 6.0?

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, tomcat6, jbpm

I have a Tomcat 6 application with JSF, Servlet, Spring, Hibernate, jBPM. I did the following to 'migrate' it to Tomcat 7.2.0.0-Final :-

1. Downloaded JBoss-7.2.0.0-Final from OpenLogic since the JBOss community has stopped with JBoss-7.1.0.0-Final (which is supposed to be 'buggy').
2. Set the datasource in JBoss standalone.xml based on values in the Tomcat server.xml. I took hints from this : [jboss 7 oracle datasource configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049882/jboss-7-oracle-datasource-configuration)
3. Made some more configuration changes based on this http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/tomcat-to-jboss-migration
4. Downloaded ojdb6.jar , created the corresponding module.xml and added it to the ojdb6.jar. Placed both of them in the JBoss-Home/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/main  folder.
5. Created a war out of the Tomcat/webapps/myApplication folder as xxx.war. (It may have had recursive war, jar. I don't know). I copied this war file to JBoss-Home/standalone/deployments folder.
6. I started JBoss server. Then i opened the management  console at `http://localhost:32080` which connects successfully to the data source, shows the war file (xxx.war) as being deployed.
7. However when i key in the URL of application at `http://localhost:32080/xxx/login.jsf`, it gives a 404 error. (There is a login.xhtml file in xxx war and i think the xhtml has been mapped to JSF somewhere).
8. In the console where i started JBoss, i get this error : "Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit "xxx.war#xxxPersistanceUnit"...:org.hibernate.MappingException : Error while parsing file : jbpm.history.hbm.xml.

Now, the Tomcat version was using jBPM 3.2. The JBoss 7.2.0.0-Final does not include the jBPM framework as far as i can see.

Maybe this question has many ambiguities, but can someone tell me what are the areas to study in order to overcome these and get the Login.jsf to start ?

Thanks and regards,
Chak.

PS:- On reviewing it looks to me that i have to integrate jBPM to my JBoss application. That may be the problem. Any thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have a war application which you want to deploy to JBoss AS 7.2. Technically the web container provided is JBoss Web. You can see the web container version bundled with JBoss AS [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS)

I have never done this exercise but I think you would need to make changes in the appropriate configuration files (which may not have same name/structure as it is in standalone Tomcat). The instructions to deploy a war file on JBoss AS is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013783/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-jboss-as-7) and on JBoss web is explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/deployer-howto.html)

Regarding dependencies, if your application needs some dependencies which are provided by Jboss AS, then you have have to enable them by enabling their respective modules. Some modules are implicitly included if your application references them in its code but some needs to be enabled explicitly because of modular nature of JBoss.